# Grouped products on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have grouped products on woocommerce and I want to check total quantity. If my condition it's ok… to add products in cart, else… no. I have no idea why but this hook it's called two times. Maybe because I have two products in the grouped product?

How can I prevent to make the hook only one time?

Bellow, what i've tried:

```
// add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');
// function custome_add_to_cart() {
//    $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

//  $quantity_total = (array_sum($_POST['quantity']));
//  echo $quantity_total;
//  if (($quantity_total % 3 != 0)  && has_term( 'My personal box', 'product_cat') ) {
//         wc_add_notice( __( 'Multiple of 7 required quantity.', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
//         $valid = false;
//     }
// }
```

Comment: Not exactly multiples, but my [Mix and Match plugin](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/) is similar to grouped products with a quantity restriction.